# Facebook FQL for retrieving a reply to a comment box comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-comments

I'm using the Facebook comment box plugin and am also subscribing the comment.create JavaScript event so that I can retrieve the details of the comment from Facebook using FQL and store that comment data in my application's database.

So far, when I receive the ID and href of the new comment (passed into the comment.create event handler), I am able to use the following FQL to retrieve the details of that comment:

```
SELECT object_id, post_id, fromid, time, text, username 
FROM comment 
WHERE post_fbid='*** EVENT COMMENT_ID ***' AND object_id 
    IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url='*** EVENT HREF ***')
```

All of this works great.

The problem occurs when a user replies to a comment.  In this case, the query above fails to retrieve the comment.

[I've done some digging around](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/) and have found that the Facebook 'comment' table apparently has a 'comments' field (or relationship, not sure) that contains the replies to the comment.  You can even use the following query to retrieve all of the replies to a comment:

```
SELECT comments
FROM comment 
WHERE post_fbid='*** EVENT COMMENT_ID ***' AND object_id 
    IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url='*** EVENT HREF ***')
```

After tinkering with the FQL test console, I can see that the replies are being added to this 'comments' field.  However, rather than trying to retrieve ALL of the replies, I'm trying to lookup the specific one whose ID I received in the comment.create event handler.  The problem is, since 'comments' appears to be a field rather than a linked table, I don't think I can query it.

Anyone else run into this?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT text, time, id, likes, fromid, comments FROM comment WHERE   is_private = 0 AND 
object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url ='YOUR_URL') or
object_id in (select post_fbid from comment where object_id in (select comments_fbid from link_stat where url ='YOUR_URL')) 
ORDER BY time DESC limit 0,10
```